# RegEx for UK area codes.

Tags: regex

I need to be able to validate UK telephone numbers when input and present them in the correct format when displayed.

I have seen several unfathomable RegEx examples but they don't get the right format for all UK numbers or reject some valid formats (or allow some invalid formats).

I found a list of the required formats and it looks right (and a lot more complicated than I first envisaged) but how do I turn this into a "simple" RegEx pattern?

NSN length:

- 10 mostly;
- 9 for some 01xxx areas;
- 9 for all 0500, some 0800;
- 7 for two special 08xx numbers.

Format:

NSN = 10:

- (01xxxx) xxxxx
- (01xxx) xxxxxx
- (01x1) xxx xxxx
- (011x) xxx xxxx
- (02x) xxxx xxxx
- 03xx xxx xxxx
- 055 xxxx xxxx
- 056 xxxx xxxx
- 070 xxxx xxxx
- 07xxx xxxxxx
- 0800 xxx xxxx
- 08xx xxx xxxx
- 09xx xxx xxxx

NSN = 9:

- (016977) xxxx
- (01xxx) xxxxx
- 0500 xxxxxx
- 0800 xxxxxx

NSN = 7:

- 0800 1111
- 0845 46 47

Notes:

- 01 ranges can have NSN as 10 or 9.
- 0800 range can have NSN as 10, 9 or 7.
- 0845 range can have NSN as 10 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest (although not the most elegant) solution would be to simply concatenate your list with the | operator e.g.:

```
\(01\d\{4}\) \d{5}|\(01\d{3}) \d{6}|(01\d1) \d{3} \d{4}|0800 1111
```

The nice thing about this is that if you write a short conversion script from the list you have to the regexp then if you get a new list in the future you can re-generate the regexp without having to do complicated debugging.

Although you could optimise this by factoring out common sub-expressions, I'd only do that if you discover that performance is a problem. Which is unlikely with a decent RE engine on modern machines.

Answer (score 0):

Take your list of valid patterns and perform these steps:

- Put `^` at the start of the line, and `$` at the end of the line.
- Put a backslash before every parenthesis.
- Replace xxxx with `[0-9]{n}` where `n` is the number of digits.
- Join each line with `|`.

You can either do these steps manually, or else you can write a program to perform the steps and generate the regex for you.

For example if you have these patterns:

- (01xxxx) xxxxx
- (01xxx) xxxxxx
- (01x1) xxx xxxx

then the regex would be this:

```
^\(01[0-9]{4}\) [0-9]{5}$|^\(01[0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{6}$|^\(01[0-9]1\) [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}$
```

You may also want to make the spaces optional by adding a question mark after them.